# Editing connection filters in SharePoint 2016 UPS

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, 2016, connection-filters

I have got SP 2016 installed in premise and I am trying to setup User Profile service application. I have successfully created my connection to AD, however, I need to filter the profiles.

When I click on Edit Connection Filters, it comes up with an alert message saying:

> This can only be used if 'SharePoint profile synchronization' is enabled in the 'Configure Synchronization Settings' for this user profile application

However, I have no such option in Configure Synchronization Settings.

Can anybody help me with this, please?

Comment: are you using the Active Directory Import or MIM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not create a filter here anymore. Your options are

1. If you are using ADI then you have to edit the connection and scroll down and you will see following text box **Filter in LDAP syntax for Active Directory Import**. Over here you have to put your LDAP filters here. If you want to filter out the disabled user then simply check the check-box. [read this for more information](http://andersrask.sharepointspace.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=39)
2. But if you are using the MIM as your profile Synchronization​ then you have to Create the Filter at SPMA and ADMA. [Check this blog for MIM](http://krossfarm.com/?p=193)

Comment: Odd that they would leave in a menu item if you can't create a filter there anymore, or at least they could give a more meaningful error/warning message.